NestJS not running POST request
I am following a tutorial by Dave Gray and by 29:30 he creates a POST controller as
@Post() // POST /users
create(@Body() user: Record<string, any>) {
  return user;
}

When I run this on postman, NOTHING happens as shown in the following screenshot.

The complete code of the file is as follows. Adding for reference. Please let me know if more detail is required.
import { Body, Controller, Get, Param, Post } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  /**
   * GET /users
   * GET /users/:id
   * POST /users
   * PATCH /users/:id
   * DELETE /users/:id
   */

  @Get() // GET /users
  findAll() {
    return [];
  }

  @Get('interns') // GET /users/intern
  findAllInterns() {
    return ['interns'];
  }

  @Get(':id') // GET /users/:id
  findOne(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return { id };
  }

  @Post() // POST /users
  create(@Body() user: Record<string, any>) {
    return user;
  }
}



are you debugging it properly? put some console.log in the method that you expect to be called. If this simple code doesn't works then almost all nestjs apps out there are broken.

Yes I am debugging it I tried console.log but it even the console.log is not showing up which means that the function is not being called. However, other HTTP methods are working fine. The problem is only with POST request

Did you add the UserController in your UserModule like here

Yes I did. which is why all other methods are working like GET, PATCH etc... Problem is only with POST requests

can you provide the GitHub repo

I tried it on a different PC with exact same configurations, and it is somhow working fine... It was a system specific issue... But still I need to figure out what is the issue with the PC I am working on. On that exact PC, I tried using express and nextjs to create POST request and it is working fine.
So the problem is now my system specific and nest specific.
